# How to get the token for streaming live video HLS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebug, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to build a personal iOS app to watch some of my favorite TV channels. To do that, I analyze a website providing live TV service. I notice that they are using HLS protocol.
By using firebug, I can see the chunklist link, then I use `MPMoviePlayerController` or `AVPlayerViewController` to play the live video. It works perfectly.
Now, I also notice that each chunklist link contains a parameter "token" at the end of it. For example:

```
.../chunklist_b300000.m3u8?token=eyJoYXNoX3ZhbHVlIjogIjQ4OWUwMGIzN2Y4ZTNlYzRlZTI4Zjg0N2I3NjQxNDEyIiwgInNlcnZlcl90aW1lIjogMTQ1NDYyNjcxMCwgImNoYW5uZWxfaWQiOiAidnRjNyIsICJ2YWxpZF9taW51dGVzIjogMTQ0MH0
```

I can use this link many times and it still works. However, if I'm using the same token on two devices at the same time, it doesn't work well. And I guess, after a duration, say several days, the token will expire.

 Therefore, I'd like to know how they generate the token. I tried to detect everything with firebug but I couldn't find out the answer. Here is the website:

[livetv](https://fptplay.net/livetv)

Is there a standard way to generate the token? And how to fetch the new token every time I open my app?

Comment: Find out the token service that they are using and ask it for tokens?

Comment: @johnelemans I tried, but the response is "403 forbidden". I think I've included all necessary parameters and headers to simulate the http request from the website on tool like "Rest Client", but it didn't work at all.

Comment: @lenhhoxung how did you append this token with the url?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way of generating (secure) tokens.

Most servers generate the token by combining the ip, mac-addresss, a client uuid of some sort, and a `secret keyworld`. Then the result is hashed using a cryptographically strong algorithm like SHA-1 or SHA-3 and base64 encoded for ease of use.

Even you if knew the combining scheme and the hashing algorithm you still wouldn't know the `secret keyword` and you couldn't generate tokens by yourself.

Some servers generate a unique token that doesn't carry any info by itself. Rather the server associates it (using a database of some sort) with some internal information (like token validity, expiration date and so on). In this case the token itself is irrelevant only the state of the server matters.

A way of generating new tokens is to make requests to the server spoofing a normal/valid user with a browser and then parse the response to get the token.

Maybe this question is more appropriate for [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange because it's not related to programming but rather to content protection.

Comment: I tried to simulate the request to get the token, but the it always returns the error 403 "forbidden". Maybe they want to protect their resources :)